# Selecting the value in a row closest to zero in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

We have a pandas `DataFrame` with two columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(12).reshape(6,2), columns=list('ab')) % 3 - 1.2

     a    b
0 -1.2 -0.2
1  0.8 -1.2
2 -0.2  0.8
3 -1.2 -0.2
4  0.8 -1.2
5 -0.2  0.8
```

What's the best way to get the values closest to zero? The expected output of the above would be

```
     x
0 -0.2
1  0.8 
2 -0.2  
3 -0.2
4  0.8 
5 -0.2
```

I tried using `df.idxmin(axis=1)`, and then `lookup`, but I'm betting there's an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use where to choose between the value in 'a' or 'b'

```
df['a'].where(df['a'].abs() < df['b'].abs(), df['b'])
```

### My original answer

You can add a column with the column name of the value closest to zero, then use it to select the closest value.

```
(df.assign(closest=df.apply(lambda x: x.abs().argmin(), axis='columns'))
 .apply(lambda x: x[x['closest']], axis='columns'))
```

Still it looks more cumbersome than it should be?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, giving you the value closest to zero:

```
   df.abs().min()
```

Comment: This would return the minimum values or indexes ?

Comment: It returns the minimum values

Comment: Is there possibility that this return row where value in close to zero?

Comment: if you want the index use:  `index=df.index[ df ==df.abs().min()]`

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(12).reshape(6,2), columns=list('ab')) % 3 - 1.2
closest_to_zero = df.abs().idxmin(axis=1).pipe(lambda x: x[x.notnull()])
pd.Series(df.lookup(closest_to_zero.index, closest_to_zero), index=closest_to_zero.index).reindex(df.index)
```