# Selecting the value in a row closest to zero in a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

This question is an extension of this question: [Selecting the value in a row closest to zero in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488781)

but expanding it to include multiple columns. Is this possible to do in one line and add the column name it came from?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-15,15,size=(6,4)).reshape(6,4), columns=list('abcd'))


     a      b      c      d
0   -2    -15     -5     -6
1   14     -3      5    -14
2   -5    -13      0     -5
3  -13      4    -10      6
4   13     -9      4      2
5   0      -7    -10      6
```

expected:

```
    closest_to_0_a_b_c_d     column
0                     -2          a
1                     -3          b
2                      0          c
3                      4          b
4                      2          d 
5                      0          a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @QuangHoang's answer, you can also return the negative value with `lookup`:

Input:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   3   4 -14 -12
1  -6  -8  -9   8
2  12 -15   7   0
3  13  -7   2 -12
4 -14 -15  -7 -14
5  13 -11   1   9
```

Output:

```
df1 = df.abs().agg(['min','idxmin'], axis=1)
df1['min'] = df.lookup(df1.index, df1['idxmin'])
df1
Out[1]: 
   min idxmin
0    3      a
1   -6      a
2    0      d
3    2      c
4   -7      c
5    1      c
```

And to rename the columns:

```
df1.columns = [f'closest_to_{"_".join(df.columns)}', 'column']
df1

Out[2]: 
   closest_to_a_b_c_d column
0                   3      a
1                  -6      a
2                   0      d
3                   2      c
4                  -7      c
5                   1      c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `agg`:

```
df.abs().agg(['min','idxmin'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  min idxmin
0   2      a
1   3      b
2   0      c
3   4      b
4   2      d
5   0      a
```

Comment: hey sorry. I just edited the question because I forgot negatives which was the whole point of it and makes it a little more tricky. Sorry!

Comment: @kindofhungry same story, you just need to take the absolute values with `.abs()`